# Will I be able to change my fork?

Tags: fork, 26-inch, 27-inch

I currently have a 26" enduro bike. It already has some years but it works perfectly. Good front 160-180mm forks for 26" wheels are becoming more and more rare. The front 26" fork will eventually die at some point. Is there any way to put a 27" fork with a 26" or 27.5" wheel? Will this destroy the geometry?.

I am just curious if I will be able to keep my bike for more years without the need to hunt for second-hand 26" forks?

Comment: Do you mean 27" or 27.5? The former is an outdated road standard, the second is currently trendy for MTBs.

Comment: I'm not sure your fear of 26inch forks disappearing is  really something to worry about. If I look for instance at [Chain Reaction Cycles](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/forks?f=2258) They actually have more 26 inch forks than 27.5 or 29 inch.  The selection of 29 inch wheels is also quite healthy.  I really don't think it's likely that 26 inch will completely disappear in less than a decade.

Comment: @Kibbee - not sure I agree.  There are a lot of 26" forks there, but only 4 of them meet the requirements of OP. 3 of them are on clearance, and the only remaining one is 730 dollars. I think realistically, for a *good* fork, he's going to end up reconditioning old forks (e.g. through Shock Therapy or whatever), or end up swapping out the bike (at some point, with the cost of the fork and labor, it becomes more appealing just to buy a new bike and take the rest of the improvements as well).

Comment: There are always donor bikes. But the reality is that's it'd just be better and most probably cheaper to retire the bike and get a new-used bike a few years time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best to stick to 26" specific forks. 27.5 forks will alter your ride handling due to the increased fork offset/rake and increased axle to crown length.

Increased fork offset/rank will reduce the fork's stability (ex. self-centering effect). The fork offset issue is a major issue, especially for higher speed gravity-assisted riding. The steering twitchiness increases, which can lead to micro-corrections when cornering (rather than a calm smooth arc) and the wheel is more liable to deflect left/right when hitting bumps head on.

Increased axle to crown length will rotate your bike's geo back, notably increasing BB height (compromised cornering and stability), slackening the seat angle (compromised seated pedaling position). Also, the reach is shortened, stack is raised, and rear center length (horizontally chainstay measurement) is increased.

You can mitigate the axle to crown length issue by running less travel up front, but then you compromise on your travel and dynamic geometry, which includes your ride height at sag and such, which would require further fine tuning.

Note that you can still get upgrade kits and custom tuning for 26" fork chassis, if you feel that it's becoming out of date. For example, RS offers a Charger damper for 26.

The industry has abandoned 26" for 27.5 for modern high end performance MTB designs. You will see fewer options down the line for forks, tires, and wheels. Expect production to be further discontinued, due to lack of demand; note that manufacturers of complete bikes are undoubtedly the biggest customers, not retailers and individuals in aftermarket.

I personally have a Stumpjumper FSR EVO with a 26" BOS Deville fork, and it has less significantly less breakaway resistance than a new Pike and 36. The damping is different, but I can't subjectively say if it's something I prefer or not; I just know that it hasn't let me down nor is repulsive in any way. Versus the prior CTD fork, I've been crashing far less (from often to almost never), but a bit of the bike's playful and thrilling character has been lost in the process (feels more behaved and mature).

Comment: The note on axel to crown length was interesting. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

So long as the fork is compatible with the frame (i.e. its for the right headset type, threaded/unthreaded, has the right steerer diameter, etc), you can run a fork for a different size wheel. Some bikes have been sold with different wheel sizes in the front and back (e.g. 69ers and 96ers). A shop should be able to help you with compatibility with your frame.

Note that the bicycle was designed with some particular configuration of fork and wheel size in mind (some amount of suspension, rake, etc.) to achieve some level of performance. Deviating from this may lead to different performance of the bike.

Comment: It's the fork length that is the issue (determined by wheel size and suspension travel). You want a fork length that is close to what you have now or steering geometry may be negatively impacted.